# Log in history and OS installation date

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, operating-system, computer-science

Actually I want to know the date when my windows operating system was installed before I purchase my laptop. And the number of logins with date and time made by seller before I purchase that.

Comment: Okay. And you want to do that with powershell or batch-file? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: See `InstallDate` property in output from `wmic os get /value`.

Comment: From cmd I typed systeminfo but in the result , I found the original installation date as the date when my system  took  upgrade from microsoft.
More ever I tried eventvwr.msc command from run  and then in the windows log I didn't find the result what I was searching for. @ jissak

Comment: From the value it says the date when my os took last update just like the result I got by using systeminfo command from cmd @ JosefZ

Answer (score 2):

login dates are stored in the event log . So you can use the `wevtutil` to query the events:

```
wevtutil qe Security /q:"*[System/EventID=4624] and *[System/Task=12544] and *[EventData/Data[@Name='LogonType']=5]" /e:Events /f:Text | find "Date:"
```

for the installation date you can use:

```
WMIC OS GET InstallDate /format:value
```

Comment: Okay ! I have one laptop and 2 desktops. In case of my laptop it shows the last update time. In case one of my desktop where the OS is 
windows 8.1 shows the actual date I installed the OS.In case of my desktop where the processor is AMD and OS is windows 10,it shows a time when I neither
installed the OS nor the OS took update from microsoft. But wanted to know the actual date of my laptop when OS installed

Comment: @Dream_Wind - you can try also `systeminfo | find /i "install date"` but it will generate the same result.I don't think there's another instrument to determine the installation date.

Answer (score 1):

Using Powershell to get desired data:

```
$date = Get-Date -Date 26.04.2016 #date when you bought your laptop
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$logons = Get-EventLog -LogName Security -EntryType SuccessAudit -InstanceId 4624 -Before $date
@{InstallDate=$wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.InstallDate);LogonsCount=$logons.count}
```

Make sure your security log was not cleaned recently to get proper values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch code with conversion date :

```
@echo off
Color 9B & Mode con cols=60 lines=3
Title The Install Date of your OS by Hackoo 2016
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('WMIC OS GET InstallDate /format:value') do (
    @for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%B in ("%%A") do (
        Call :ConvertDate %%B
    )>"%~n0.txt"
)

for /f "delims=" %%D in ('Type "%~n0.txt"') do ( set InstallDate=%%D )
echo(
echo    The Install Date of your OS is : %InstallDate%
pause>nul
Exit /b
::**********************************************************************
Rem Function for Converting WMI Dates to a Standard Date-Time Format
:ConvertDate <Date>
(
    echo WScript.echo WMIDateStringToDate("%~1"^)
    echo Function WMIDateStringToDate(Mydate^)
    echo  WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(Mydate, 5, 2^) ^& "/" ^& _
    echo  Mid(Mydate, 7, 2^) ^& "/" ^& Left(Mydate, 4^) _
    echo  ^& " " ^& Mid (Mydate, 9, 2^) ^& ":" ^& _
    echo  Mid(Mydate, 11, 2^) ^& ":" ^& Mid(Mydate,13, 2^)^)
    echo End Function
)>"%~n0.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%~n0.vbs" "%~1"
Del "%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::**********************************************************************
```